# Can I automate my spring-boot docker builds with the dockerfile or would Jenkins be more appropriate?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, jenkins, github

After first attempts of setting up automated docker builds for my personal spring-boot github repos (I'm a newbie) they were constantly failing due to the jar file not being found. While my first impression was that I had the pathing wrong, it dawned on me that docker wasn't building the jars before attempting the builds.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/myjar*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} myjar.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myjar.jar"]
```

While I have found a couple of resouces that describe how to integrate maven into the Dockerfile, it seemed like my image could easily get too big too easily with that approach. Has anybody tackled this issue before and could recommend recommend a way to integrate maven into the Dockerfile build? An alternative I've given thought to is to learn Jenkins and develop a solution that way for a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to achieve this.

**Approach 1**

Rely on the maven with its [docker maven plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin)
   This indeed allows building the image during the maven build.

This approach will work in general and allows a level of customizations sufficient for 
many use cases. Usually, spring boot applications come as a single Jar with all the dependencies packed inside it, so there is no need for multiple layers in docker image (at least in my experience).

The point here is to call the plugin when the jar of spring boot is already built. 
   The jar is prepared with the help of another plugin and it is usually invoked in `package` phase, so if you go with this approach, make sure that you invoke the image creation plugin after the spring boot maven plugin that builds the single jar artifact.

The artifact must reside in `<you_module>/target` folder and it will be pretty big in size. The original module will reside next to it but will have the suffix `.original`.

**Approach 2**

Let maven build the artifact but not the image. Maven will end after this step.
Then invoke a script in Jenkins that will run the `docker build` command and it will build the image.

The result will be the same, you'll work here with docker directly possibly utilizing all its perks if you really need it.

Both approaches can work for you, choosing between them depends on the following factors:

- You're more a Java / maven guy rather than devops guy - then go with approach 1 otherwise go with approach 2
- You would like to actually locally run the image that you've built, for example, if you have a kubernetes cluster installed locally - in this case, go with approach 1
- You need to utilize some latest features of docker not available for use from the plugin - then go with approach 2

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the plugin in my searches but hadn't given it too much thought before. I'll likely take that path for now